# cant find emulator on android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart

INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.12.0 (build_id 9751036) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\ WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib\advancedFeaturesCanary.ini for reading. WARNING | Failed to load advanced feature default setting:C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib\advancedFeaturesCanary.ini ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | IPv4 server found: 218.248.112.65

i tried redownloading everything nothing works

Comment: delete this emulator & create a new one. maybe will work

Comment: thanks but its not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I duplicated the AVD and it worked

[image: 3 dots > Duplicate > copied emulator functions correctly]